# How can I testfor only one player in a specific place?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map and I need to testfor the last player alive in the arena. I tried with selectors, but I am not really into this. Can someone help me out?

Comment: use /stats in combination with testfor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/testforblock` to check the success of a command block.

[image: Repeating > conditional chain > conditional chain]

1. Test for the number of players in the area. The `c` value is set to 2 to lower the amount of processing that would need to be done (since you only want to know if there are 1 or more players).

   ```
   /testfor @a[10,64,10,30,c=2]
   ```
2. **Conditional**. Check the `SuccessCount` value of the repeating command block. Change `X Y Z` to the repeating command block's coordinates.

   ```
   /testforblock X Y Z minecraft:repeating_command_block -1 {SuccessCount:1}
   ```
3. **Conditional**. Command to run if there was only 1 player.

   ```
   /say Finished.
   ```

Comment: Can you tell me what "10,64,10,30" means? They are coordinates?

Comment: @iDoomfull Yes, it's the short-hand method of specifying coordinates and a radius. At the beginning of the parameters you can specify just numbers, which represents "x", "y", "z", and "r" in that order. It would be the same as `@a[x=10,y=64,z=10,r=30]` (and is up to you which you want to use, as the only difference is convenience).

Answer (score 0):

Create a scoreboard

> /scoreboard objectives add testScoreBoard dummy

Chech for amount of players in radius r

> /stats entity @e[type=Player,r=10] set SuccessCount testScoreBoard @p

You can then say something if there are 2 player in range

> /execute @p[score_scoreBoardTest_min=2] ~ ~ ~ say 2 players are in range

Reset the scoreboard every tick

> /scoreboard players reset testScoreBoard @p

Put all those commands into repeating command blocks.

I'm using @p because i need a placeholder wich i can select with selectors. You can use a ArmorStand tho:

> /stats entity @e[type=Player,r=10] set SuccessCount testScoreBoard @e[type=ArmorStand,tag=counter]
>
> /execute @e[tag=counter,score_scoreBoardTest_min=2] ~ ~ ~ say 2 players are in range
>
> /scoreboard players reset testScoreBoard @e[tag=counter]

Hope it helped :)

Comment: You should apply the CommandStats to a command block instead of to players, setting the score of a fake player instead of real players. Since it's a single area that would be preferable over possible complications of players logging out or dying (in which they would change a different player's score instead of their own since you've used `@p` is the trigger target). But CommandStats in this case is quite overkill.

Comment: i did not do so much with the stat command, just a quick idea wich came into my mind. Thanks for the correction :)